# AWS Chalice with Dropbox API timeout

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

I have been unable to get dropbox python api to work with AWS Chalice. Whenever I have an `import dropbox` statement in app.py or anywhere else in the application, the command works in `chalice local` for localhost deployments, but timeout when I deploy it into AWS via `chalice deploy`.

The deployment works perfectly, but when I try even the most basic endpoints such as

```
@app.route('/')
def index():  
    return {"hello" : "world"}
```

the request times out at the / route.

Dropbox Version: 10.3.1
Chalice Version: 1.18.0

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue was because too little memory was allocated to the lambda function as dropbox is a fairly large package. Increasing the memory limit from 128mb to 512mb resolves the problem.